# I tried this as a method in my View Controller, but I'd really like it in a Label

Tags: ios, uilabel, categories, nsnumberformatter

I really want to implement a category like 'UILabel+formattedText' that allows me to perform a method which will nicely format the text in the label's visible display, but any code that looks at label.text just sees the unformatted number string. I know this is probably very simple. Thing is, I can't seem to find the syntax for that. How would that work exactly?

Here's my rough draft for the method inside the view controller:

```
- (void)UpdateLabels{
    if(!formatter){//initialize formatter if there isn't one yet.
        formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        [formatter setPositiveFormat:@",##0.##"]; 
        [formatter setNegativeFormat:@",##0.##"];
        [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:15];
        [formatter setMaximumIntegerDigits:15];

    }
    NSRange eNotation =[rawDisplay rangeOfString: @"e"];//if there's an 'e' in the string, it's in eNotation.
    if ([rawDisplay isEqual:@"Error"]) {
        display.text=@"Error";
        backspaceButton.enabled = FALSE;
    }else if (eNotation.length!=0) {
        //if the number is in e-notation, then there's no special formatting necessary.
        display.text=rawDisplay;
        backspaceButton.enabled =FALSE;
    } else {
        backspaceButton.enabled =([rawDisplay isEqual:@"0"])? FALSE: TRUE; //disable backspace when display is "0"            
        //convert the display strings into NSNumbers because NSFormatters want NSNumbers
        // then convert the resulting numbers into pretty formatted strings and stick them onto the labels
        display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[rawDisplay doubleValue]]]];           
    }
}
```

So I basically want at least the label drawing functionality to go into the label. Is this code being true to MVC by the way? It's my first try.

Also while I'm here I may as well ask: this goes into e notation with relatively few digits as a double. But when I try to change double to something else such as longlong I get very weird results. How can I have more precision and still do all these operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest writing a subclass of UILabel. Since all you want to do is change how the text is displayed, you just need to write a custom `drawTextInRect:` method. It will use a format the value from `self.text` and draw the resulting string. Then you just need to change the class of any label which should be formatted.

Example:

```
@interface NumericLabel : UILabel {}
@end

@implementation NumericLabel
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    static NSNumberFormatter *formatter;
    NSString *text = nil, *rawDisplay = self.text;

    if(!formatter){
        //initialize formatter if there isn't one yet.
    }
    NSRange eNotation =[rawDisplay rangeOfString: @"e"];//if there's an 'e' in the string, it's in eNotation.
    if ([rawDisplay isEqual:@"Error"]) {
        text = @"Error";
    }else if (eNotation.length!=0) {
        text = rawDisplay;
    } else {
        text=[formatter stringFromNumber: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[rawDisplay doubleValue]]];           
    }

    [text drawInRect:rect withFont:self.font lineBreakMode:self.lineBreakMode alignment:self.textAlignment];
}
@end
```

Comment: when i asked if i should do that last week, people didn't seem to like that...  but yeah that's pretty good too... i'm just learning about this stuff and i'm gratified that the code above even works. I'm sure it can be done much more nicely, but that's for the future. can you give me an example in code showing how this would look?

Comment: @Dave I added example code. I also changed the answer to show that you should use `drawTextInRect:` instead of `drawRect:`. Note that the example doesn't enable/disable the backspace, since a view shouldn't do that in MVC (and you should do it before the view is displayed).

Comment: thanks for that. I thought i'd figured it out but i guess not.. changing to the custom label killed this code:         `//Dynamic display resizing.
        self.numberOfLines=1;
        self.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
        self.minimumFontSize=15.0f;` which in this iteration i tried to stick into the init method of the custom label... no? where do i put that?

Comment: The font autosizing probably occurs in the drawing routine. Since you do custom drawing, you will have to implement it yourself. Look at the [`sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:) method to calculate the font size you should use for drawing.

Comment: somebody correctly explained to me the helpful fact that it's a huge resource hog to have this in a label that may be called and redrawn many more times than the text changes... so i've put it all back into the view controller where i suppose it belongs, and all is well, heh. also the other big mistake was not calling `super` to do the drawing work, since it could...